# HTML audio playing on page load

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Im using an

```
<button id="collect" class="btn">button</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#collect').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        <?php if($soundFx == true){ ?>
            var sound = document.getElementById("collect_a");
            sound.play();
        <?php } ?>

... //script continues

</script>
```

to fire some javascript which contains a very basic sound (which is only called on a button click/form submit)

```
var sound = document.getElementById("collect_a");
sound.play();
```

which targets

```
<audio id="collect_a" src="audio/collect.wav" autoplay="false" autostart="false" preload ="none" ></audio>
```

Everything works fine, sound plays on click and no other problems with that.

However the audio is getting played on the page load/refresh, it plays all the audio at once and then stops and behaves as expected. I have read that the tags

```
autoplay="false" autostart="false" preload ="none"
```

should all help but none of them solve my issue so im wondering what i am doing wrong. The  is just placed in the html page, so does it fire automatically whether called or not? surely those tags would prevent that?

I've tried a seperate .js to call the play() function, as well as my (current) way of having it as part of my existing code, they both work, but also both play everything on load.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We need more code, how your `click()` function looks like? `.click(function(event)` is not all you have I think. Also, does it autoplay even if javascript is disabled? With no scripts at all?

Comment: i edited to add more information

Comment: Show us an actual reproducible example.  Your PHP is unnecessary, show us what makes it to the browser.  There's not enough information here to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the javascript code within the page, clear the cache and see if the audio still auto-plays (it should not). If it doesn't, it means some part of your script triggers the play function without user interaction.

Add back in al your javascript, and comment out the click event handler you mentioned. Check if the audio still plays on page reload. If it doesn't, it means something triggers the click event of your button, which in turn plays the audio. If it does play, it means some other part of your code calls the play() method of your audio element.

Use console.log() within your code to follow the flow of execution.

Or simply add an `alert('Clicked');` within your event handler and see if that shows up without you clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP but by the JavaScript within the PHP tag:

```
<?php if($soundFx == true){ ?>
  var sound = document.getElementById("collect_a");
  sound.play();
<?php } ?>
```

says *"if `$soundFX` is true (even if it has to be duck typed) then reference the audio tag and `.play()` the file loaded in the audio tag. Don't know what `$soundFX` is but I'm sure that it was declared in the real code thereby making the condition always true when the page is loaded. So remove the condition:

<del>if($soundFx == true){</del>...

Normally the event handler will not fire when page loads, but it's in PHP tags and I'm not 100% sure but I believe whatever is in PHP tags is parsed and executed. If so, you really don't need PHP for such a trivial task. You should remove the PHP tags as well. In the following demo is a simple toggle button that toggles an audio tag to play/pause in jQuery -- no PHP.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  const A = $('audio')[0];
  A.paused || A.ended ? A.play() : A.pause();
});
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>⏯</button>
<audio src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/chinese-gong-daniel_simon.mp3"></audio>.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```